# Notation for graph adjacency

Tags: graph-theory, notation

Which is the best manner to express symbolically the adjacency relation in a graph? Is there a common notation for this?

More specifically I would like to avoid things as $\{v, w\} \in E(X)$, where $E(X)$ is "edges of the graph $X$". I've seen in some notes the notation $v \sim w$, but I don't like the idea of using a symbol like $\sim$ for a non reflexive, non transitive relation.

Comment: The short and clear $vw\in E$

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek, I would like to avoid mentioning the set of edges (I have different graphs in the same proof), besides, I also have a group acting on vertices, so this would lead to some unpleasant notations such as $gvhu \in E(T')$ or similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$v\sim w$ is the standard notation here. I'm working from home so don't have access to textbooks as sources, but I have never seen anything else used instead. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)):

> The edges of a directed simple graph permitting loops $G$ is a homogeneous relation $\sim$ on the vertices of $G$ that is called the adjacency relation of $G$. Specifically, for each edge $(x,y)$, its endpoints $x$ and $y$ are said to be adjacent to one another, which is denoted $x\sim y$.

(They mention the most general case of directed graphs perhaps with loops, but the same notation is certainly used for undirected graphs.)